# Google app script import CSVs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-api

Okay.  Multiple people use the scanpet app to create csv files of 3 columns [uniformly structured, no headers in csv].

I'd like them to email the created file to a gmail account, then go to a google form.  I realize for this to work it's have to be done after each email submitted and that is okay... please read to end.

I'd like to make a google form with only one option, just to enter a record to trigger an event.  Link the form to a google sheet.  I'd like this sheet to house the script I'm asking help for in the script editor, and the google sheet to then have two other tabs named Transfer and MailOrder each with the same 3 columns as the csv files.

After the employee sends the file he completes the google form.

script triggers on form submit, and will grab the the latest csv attachment from gmail and depending on the subject line of the email (Mail Order or Transfer) add the values to the existing data entries under the tab with the same name as the subject line.

Comment: Looks like not for coding help. You can get the work done here https://sites.google.com/view/digitalthoughts/contact